How can I animate one object being the child of two bones?
I’m trying to make a reload animation, but I'm trying to switch the gun from the right arm to the left arm (Holding the gun with the left arm, mag action with right arm).
I've tried using visual location and rotation keyframes along with adjusting influence for the Child Of constraints. But sometimes the gun location and rotation will bug out. I’m using two child of constraints for the gun’s main body.

You should just need one constraint, not two. Try it with just one, and real parenting to the other bone. For more info, we’ll most likely need additional details.

You can add to a bone an armature bone constraint, adding more than one target bone and animating its weight (influence).
It's better not to use more than one child of constraint.

